# Setting PHP variable path for Cygwin

Tags: php, windows, bash, cygwin, xampp

I am having a lot of difficulty routing PHP to cygwin.

My goal is simply to run the following PHP test command successfully:

`php -v`

I'm currently getting the following error: `-bash: php: command not found`

This is what I tried in the `.bash_profile` document:

```
PATH = $PATH:/xampp/php
export PATH
```

I am using xampp and my `php.exe` is in the following path `C:/xampp/php/php.exe`, also I noticed there isn't a `bin` directory in my `php` directory. There **is** a `bin` directory in `C:/xampp/apache` perhaps this is the one I should link to? I tried this as well with no success.

Comment: What happens if you `cd /xampp/php` and try `php -v` there?

Comment: Still getting the `command not found` error

Comment: Are you sure it's in `C:/xampp/php/php.exe`?  if you `ls` you  should see it there right?  You might not have execute permissions on it?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure it is in `C:/xampp/php/php.exe` yes when I `ls` its in there.

Comment: maybe you have to type `php.exe -v`

Comment: Nope, I am still getting the command not found error.

Comment: Could it be that the current dir is not in your path? try `./php.exe` when you're in the directory.

Comment: Use `which php` to verify your shell can find the executable. Windows has a version call `where`.

Answer (score 10):

In Cygwin you windows C drive is mounted to `/cygdrive/c/` so if you wanted to add `C:/xampp/php/` to your path, then you should add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php
```

Comment: `.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, while `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells (See [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)). To set the PATH you should be able to use either. Try putting it in the other and make sure you close and reopen your terminal.

Comment: If that does not work run the following command

    PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php

Then try `php -v`. If that works then the .bashrc or .bashprofile isn't updating your PATH variable correctly. If not are you still getting `-bash: php: command not found`?

Comment: Also, make it sure you run the bash as Administrator for the changes make effect.

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh Could you provide any more detail about what is not working? What happens with you run the command above in your terminal? What is the output of `echo $PATH` after running the command? What about `which php`?

Comment: @flungo: I have tried this solution but that didn't work for me so I have created environment variable in windows.

Answer (score 3):

What @flungo wrote was absolutely correct:
I have to add this line to C:\cygwin64\etc\bash.bashrc in order for each new cygwin terminal to have the correct `$PATH`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php
```